# The YouTube option "open transcript" is not working

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

I have a problem in my Chrome browser (not in other browsers):
The YouTube option "open transcript" stopped working. It's showing an empty box without content like there were no captions at all.

There is always a result like this:

[image]

Could someone help me to fix this? :)

The problem occurs only when I'm signed in my google account.

Comment: If you specifically say *in my Chrome browser*, what happens in other browsers?

Comment: In the other browsers, it's worked normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem vanished after two weeks, I don't know how (YT actualization maybe?)

I have actualized, reinstalled Chrome changed the account setting, etc. nothing's helped.
If someone has the same issue then it may be helpful that the problem hasn't occurred in other browsers.